# database operation on javascript in MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on a mvc project. I have a button in my view which is calling a Javascript function to print the data. Code is as follows:

```
 <input type="button" class="btn_image" style="padding-top: 22px;" onclick="PrintDiv();"
        value="Print token" />

<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function PrintDiv() {
        var divToPrint = document.getElementById('printableArea');
        var popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=300,height=300');
        popupWin.document.open();
        popupWin.document.write('<html><body onload="window.print()">' + printableArea.innerHTML + '</html>');
        popupWin.document.close();
    }

</script>
</head>
```

Now I want to update record in database that this record has been printed. How can I do this? May I execute stored procedure in Javascript?

Comment: gujju lago chho tame... anyways what about using ajax call and passing data to controller and doing update operation in action method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can call a ActionResult in controller from client side using Jquery ajax.**

```
function PrintDiv() {
        var divToPrint = document.getElementById('printableArea');
        var popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=300,height=300');
        popupWin.document.open();
        popupWin.document.write('<html><body onload="window.print()">' + printableArea.innerHTML + '</html>');
        popupWin.document.close();
        UpdateDb();
    }

function UpdateDb();
{    
    $.ajax({
               type: 'POST',
                url: "@Url.Content("/Contrller/ActionResult/")",    
                data : {                          
                                 parameter1:value1,
                                 parameter1: value2
                          },           
                dataType: datatype,
                success:function(result)
                {
                   //Any thing needed to be done on success                  
                }
       });
}
```

Now write your logic to update Db in your `Actionresult` in `Controller`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: i changed the code as per your code but its not calling controller and moreover i dont know how to debug script please help

Comment: if you want to debug put debugger keyword in java-script. Also please post your $.ajax function code, there might be some syntax error which causing the issue.

Comment: function UpdateDb() {
            debugger;
            $.ajax({
                       type: 'POST',
                       url: "@Url.Content(" / TakeAppointmentController / PrintToken / ")",    
                        success:function(result)
                        {
                           //Any thing needed to be done on success                  
                        }
               });
        }

Comment: Make sure there are no spaces inside  "@Url.Content(" / TakeAppointmentController / PrintToken / ")"..also so ur not passing any parameters to actionresult right?

Comment: no i just wanna call controller that's it so , have not passed any parameters..i put alert and checked its calling UpdateDb() function but prob is with $.ajax call i guess so..

Comment: [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult PrintToken()
        {
            return View();
        }

Comment: We should n't return view from here-[HttpPost] public JsonResult PrintToken() { return Json(true); }, check this - also add dataType: "json", in $.ajax method. Hope it helps

Comment: did the same and put break point on the method but break point not firing !! what is d prob still ?

Comment: Just noticed ur URL - "@Url.Content("/TakeAppointment/PrintToken/")". - this is enough right?

Answer (score 0):

In general you never want to allow your View to access the database. That kind of access should be granted on an infrastructure level. I generally would not recommend this but at least do the database call on your Controller and then pass an  IEnumerable to the View for the table.

Comment: yeah i wanna call controller from view so searching for that solution right now..

Answer (score 0):

```
$.post("/Home/GetState/", { data : $("#printablearea").val() }, function (response) {

                         your code..
                });
```

and in controller action

```
public actionresult GetState(string data)
{
    datatable item = entity.datatable.contains(data);
    entity.entry(item)..State = EntityState.Modified;
    entity.savechanges():
}
```