# Problems updating database with Jquery.Ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am working on a website and would like to be able to update a field on a database table when a div is clicked. I found some example code right [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14812454/database-operation-on-javascript-in-mvc) on stack but for some reason it won't work, even though it was accepted. I am using C# ASP.NET MVC Razor.

My JavaScript function is as follows:

```
function toggleContent(id, instID) {
    var doc = document.getElementsByClassName("messageContent")[id];
    $(doc).slideToggle();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "@Url.Content('/Messages/MarkSeen/')",
        data: {
            instanceID : instID
        },
        dataType: 'json'
    });
}
```

And my JsonResult is as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult MarkSeen(int instanceID)
{
    var markSeen = db.MessageInstances.First(mi => mi.MessageInstanceId == instanceID);
    if (markSeen.RegisteredPerson.PersonId == CurrentUser.PersonId)
    {
        markSeen.Seen = true;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return Json(true);
    }
    return Json(false);
}
```

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: when you said it doesn't work, do you able to see any network request being sent when you click the div ? If yes, what is the response ?

Comment: Is there any reason why you are using @Url.Content instead of @Url.Action?

Comment: @tabz100 I'm using `@Url.Content` because that's what was used in the example, changing it to Action doesn't help

Comment: @StephenMuecke it's not updating the database

Comment: @user3189142 Is there an error in the request (e.g. Are you actually hitting your code or is there a problem in the request-Does the console say that there is an error?)

Comment: Is it hitting the controller method? (you really should be using `url: '@Url.Action("MarkSeen", "Messages")',` And why do you return json but then never use it in the ajax callback?

Comment: @StephenMuecke @tabz100 I changed it to use `@Url.Action` but it didn't help any, also I would like to get the request working before I do stuff with the result. There is nothing in the console to indicate an error, just a bunch of iisexpress stuff

Comment: Do you hit the `db.SaveChanges();` line in the controller?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I put a breakpoint at the start of the JsonResult, the function didn't get called

Comment: @user3189142 Do you see the network request in the console?

Comment: @tabz100 I don't, the output from Debug has nothing but the iisexpress.exe stuff from when I launch the project

Comment: @user3189142 I mean the web console (e.g. Chrome console Ctrl + Shift+ J)

Comment: @user3189142, In the browser, use F12 to open the developer tools. Inspect both the Console tab and the Network tab

Comment: @tabz100 it gives 404 not found

Comment: @user3189142 Replace "@Url.Content('/Messages/MarkSeen/')" with '@Url.Content("/Messages/MarkSeen/")' and see what happens (Swap single and double quotes)

Comment: @tabz100 I replaced it as you said and it still gives a 404 error

Comment: @user3189142, You should be using `url: '@Url.Action("MarkSeen", "Messages")',`. Is your controller named `MessagesController`? Are you using areas at all?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Controller is named `MessagesController`. Using `@Url.Action` has no difference over `@Url.Content`

Comment: @user3189142 Did you recompile before you tested out the ajax code?

Comment: @user3189142 Try this in url part url: "@Url.Content("/Messages/MarkSeen/")",

Comment: @StephenMuecke @tabz100 I changed it to `url: "../Messages/MarkSeen"` and it works now, idk why it didn't work with `@Url.Action`

Comment: Because almost certainly you are using areas and you have not specified the area in `@Url.Action()` !

Comment: @StephenMuecke it's a group project and I didn't create it originally, I don't know about areas as I'm new to asp.net mvc

Comment: It needs to be something like `url: '@Url.Action("MarkSeen", "Messages", new { area = "" })',` (or `area="someAreaName"` depending on which area you are currently in and which area your POST method is in)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where your code fails, so I posted complete working code
If you are using the ApiController, please try the following updates to make your code works:
1. add route to WebApiConfig.cs

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

2. javascript

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Content("/api/lab/MarkSeen")",
            data: { "instanceID": instID },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) { alert(data)},
            error: function () { alert('error'); }
        });
```

3. Add model to match the json from ajax request:

```
public class labModel
{
    public int instanceID { get; set; }
}
```

4. Controller:

```
[System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
public JsonResult<bool> MarkSeen(labModel data)
{
    return Json(true);
}
```